# Need more information concerning logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

I need easy explanation please :slight_smile: I am a beginner in logstash
I have some questions :slight_smile:

1. What is the tag `_gorkparsefailure` and it used for? if I delete this tag what will happen?
2. How to remove the tag `multiline`?
3. How can I make a condition from a field of my grok (condition in grok)?
4. What is `endpoint`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. grok{} is a filter used to parse larger fields (like an entire log line) into smaller fields.  If your pattern doesn't match the input given, a tag of "_grokparsefailure" will be added to the event.  If you delete it, you will lose the knowledge that such a failure occurred.  I would suggest finding the cause of the failure and resolving that instead.
2. You can remove a tag with the remove_tag param available on most filters.  The mutate{} filter is a common one to use for this:

   mutate {
       remove_tag => [ "multiline" ]
   }
3. If I understand the question correctly, you can use a field that was created by grok{} in a conditional to run some other filter:

   if [myField] == "myValue" {
      ...
   }
4. Generically, an endpoint is a destination.  In the ELK world, I only see it used in the http{} input and output, which are using to describe a website as the destination.

Comment: These explanations help me better understand :)